# Applying a cube-LUT with CIFilter.colorCube()?

Tags: swift, core-image

I'm trying to apply a LUT created in Davinci Resolve (33 points cube-format, not sure why 33 and not 32 - but Davinci doesn't have 32 as an option) on an Image. I guess I have misunderstood the format colorCube expects. It's probably not as simple as loading a standard cube-file and assigning the data. I have tried finding information what kind of data it needs but I only find old code without any explanation.

I get the following error when running the app:

`CoreImage001[13273:6135799] CIColorCube inputCubeData is not of the expected length.`

And this is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreImage
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var image: Image?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            image?
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
        }
        .onAppear(perform: loadImage)
    }
    
    func loadImage() {
        guard let inputImage = UIImage(named: "testImage") else { return }
        let ciImage = CIImage(image: inputImage)
        
        let filter = CIFilter.colorCube()
        if let lutURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "testLut", withExtension: "cube") {
            guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: lutURL) else { return }
            filter.inputImage = ciImage
            filter.cubeData = data
            filter.cubeDimension = 33
        }

        let context = CIContext()
        guard let outputImage = filter.outputImage else { return }
        if let cgImage = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent) {
            let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please check how many bytes the cube data has? It should be 33*33*33*4*4 = 574,992 (dimensions * 4 color channels * size of float).